# How to Rewrite Rule in CyberPanel to take off www?

Tags: cyber-panel

I am trying to enter my website using CyberPanel but when I try to enter the www appears so can´t enter. I have to Rewrite the Rule but I don´t know how

#### Rewrite Rules Added by CyberPanel Rewrite Rule Generator

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.[NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http:www//%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

#### End CyberPanel Generated Rules.

```
cat: /home/simulaserp.com.br/public_html/.htaccess: No such file or directory
```

that is my Rewrite Rule right now

I tried deleting the www or putting in parentheses

Comment: Please try some options that you find online. After you tried harder and harder, different options, then when you get stuck put here that piece of code, where you got stuck.

Comment: Try this code and give us feedback. `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]`